# Make Ajax call off hyperlink

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is there a way to make an Ajax call from a hyperlink?

I'd like to change the inner html of a div element when someone clicks on a hyperlink using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Ajax is just "something you can do with JavaScript"

Hyperlinks can have event handlers bound on them like any other HTML element.

```
var links_in_document = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var a_link = links_in_document[0];
a_link.addEventListener('click', a_function_that_does_something_ajaxy);

function a_function_that_does_something_ajaxy(e) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // etc
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Note: No compatibility routines for browsers that don't support standards are included in this code sample. You should add some (along with a more sensible way to determine which link you are targeting).

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="javascript:yourAjaxFunctionName();">click</a>
```

Comment: Eugh. Please no. Can we leave that syntax behind in the the '90s? Be [progressive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: you are right. Its backdated. But I though it will be easier for him to understand.